# Get altitude of click position CesiumJS with Google Photorealistic 3D Tileset

Tags: cesiumjs, google-3d-tileset

This is the example demo app

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Google%20Photorealistic%203D%20Tiles.html

I tried to add altitude from [this snippet](https://community.cesium.com/t/getting-the-height-at-mouse-location/19272) (modified so can onclick instead mousemove)

below the original code and then run (F8) but it shows error that it doesn't have globe object.

```
handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);
handler.setInputAction(function (event) {
  let ray = viewer.camera.getPickRay(event.position);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ray));
  let mousePosition = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene); 
  // error because globe undefined ^
  if (Cesium.defined(mousePosition)) {
    let cartographic = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(mousePosition);
    let latStr = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude);
    let lonStr = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude);
    let heightStr = cartographic.height;
    console.log(latStr, lonStr, heightStr)
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

If I tried to enable the `globe: true`, it failed on initialization phase of CesiumJS.

tried also solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291013/get-ground-altitude-cesiumjs) but 2nd answer not having globe object if using google tileset, 1st answer only get the land altitude, not click altitude.

How can I get altitude (preferably sea level, or any kind is altitude fine), from a mouse click?

Or alternatively is there any more complete 3d tileset other than google [3d photorealistic 3d tileset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/3d-tiles) that I can use that can get the altitude position of a click?